# How can I programmatically access performance metrics of Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to access metrics such as Requests/sec, Capacity, RUs, etc - programmatically.  Have access to API tokens/etc.  Not seeing a .NET management nuget package for DocumentDb

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read metrics from the Azure Insights SDK. The .NET SDK i currently in preview https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Insights

The Rest API documentation is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

To list all metrics you can call the following endpoint (you'll need to include the Bearer token in the authorization header)

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group of your documentDB}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/{documentDB account name}/metricDefinitions?api-version=2015-04-08

This will list all available metric definitions. You can then use a query like this to read the induvidual metrics.

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subecriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/{DocumentDB account}/metrics?api-version=2015-04-08&$filter=%28name.value%20eq%20%27Total%20Requests%27%29%20and%20timeGrain%20eq%20duration%27PT5M%27%20and%20startTime%20eq%202016-05-28T20%3A26%3A00.0000000Z%20and%20endTime%20eq%202016-05-29T20%3A26%3A00.0000000Z

For more info on reading metrics, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/23/retrieving-resource-metrics-via-the-azure-insights-api/